# Selecting 11/5 out of 30 students.

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to select a team consists of 11 members for baseball and other 5 members for basketball, from a class of 30 people?

Comment: Your question is unclear, can a student join both teams?

Comment: **Remark:** Assuming that students can't join both teams, the order in which you select the teams (baseball first versus basketball first) doesn't matter. That is, both of these quantities are equivalent:
$$
\binom{30}{11}\binom{19}{5} = \binom{30}{5}\binom{25}{11}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a student is **allowed** to join both teams:

$$\text{there are }{30\choose11}{30\choose5}\text{ ways;}$$

If a student is **not allowed** to join both teams, then:

$$\text{there are }{30\choose11}{19\choose5}\text{ ways.}$$

Answer (score 2):

We choose $11$ students from $30$ and we choose $5$ from $19$ so the number of possibility is:
$${30\choose 11}\times {19\choose5}$$

Answer (score 1):

I shall assume a student can join both teams 
For baseball

${{30}\choose{11}} = \frac{30!}{(30-11)!11!} = 54627300$

for basketball

${{30}\choose{5}} = \frac{30!}{(30-5)!5!} = 142506$

The product of these is the final solution

For choosing r items from a sample of n use [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

Answer (score 1):

First, there are $(^{30}_{11})$ ways of selecting a team of $11$ out of a group of $30$; then there are $(^{19}_{5})$ ways of selecting a team of $5$ out of the remaining $19$ members of the group. So the total number of ways is the product $$ (^{30}_{11}) \cdot (^{19}_{5}) = \frac{30!}{11! \cdot 19!} \cdot \frac{19!}{5! \cdot 14!} = \frac{30!}{11! \cdot 5! \cdot 14!} = .... $$

Hope you can now calculate the exact figure with paper and pencil or with the help of a calculater.